# Get Range of a previously marked Excel cell in VSTO

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, excel-addins

I'm writing a VSTO Add-In for Excel 2013/2016 in C#.

The add-in needs to mark a specific cell in an Excel worksheet somehow. (This mark needs to survive the closing of the workbook.) Then the Add-In needs to insert data at this specific cell. Therefore I need to get the position/range of this cell.

What is the best way to mark a cell and how do i get the position of that marked cell?

Is there a better solution than searching every cell for a keyword like "&?%insertHere" ?

Answer (score 2):

You could insert a comment into the cell. Then loop the used range per sheet looking for the comment.

```
Excel.Range cell; 
cell.AddComment("Insert Here");
```

Comment: That's a good idea, thank you. Iterating over the whole usedRange can be inefficient though.
You could get all Comments by `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet.Comments` and iterate over these instead. But I don't know how to get the range/cell/position of a comment. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

One way to mark a cell is naming it:

```
// Name a cell (here: the active cell in the active Excel sheet)
Excel.Range cell = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveCell;
cell.Name = "MyMarkedCell";

// Get a cell by its name
Worksheet sheet = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;
Excel.Range cell = sheet.get_Range("MyMarkedCell");
// Careful: get_Range throws an Exception, when there is no cell with the given name.
```

#### Pros:

- Has no effect on the value/content of the cell, and is therefore not
  seen in the (printed) document
- can be done in Excel application and in code
- easy adding or editing of named cells
- is saved in the workbook file and survives closing
- accessing a named cell is fast, because the application doesn't iterate over 
  all cells of the sheet

#### Cons:

- Only one cell can be named with a specific name. If this name is assigned 
  to another cell, the old one is simply unnamed. So a user could easily 
  destroy the whole procedure.